# How can a dataframe containing a vector list have a different length when unlisted?

Tags: r, list, vector, apply

Given a data frame with `n` length, I ran an apply function and assigned the result to a new column on the dataframe:

```
my_df$index <- sapply(my_df$local_db_uuid,function(x) which(my_df$remote_db_uuid== x))
```

However, I noticed the following:

```
join_ref_id_complete$index %>% length()
# returns length of dataframe rows
```

Versus:

```
join_ref_id_complete$index %>% unlist() %>% length()
# returns less than length of dataframe rows
```

What is going on here with the length? Are these missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that some `list` elements doesn't have a match and returns `integer(0)` which gets dropped while `unlist`ing.  Using a simple example

```
lst1 <- list(c(5, 0), c(3, 2, 4), 5)
sapply(lst1, function(x) which(x == 5))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#integer(0)

#[[3]]
#[1] 1
```

when we `unlist`, the second element is dropped

```
unlist(sapply(lst1, function(x) which(x == 5)))
#[1] 1 1
```

returning a `length` of 2 instead of 3

But, it is just a coincidence that the length is less.  It can be greater ass well

```
lst1 <- list(c(5, 0, 5, 5), c(3, 2, 4), c(5, 3, 5))
unlist(sapply(lst1, function(x) which(x == 5)))
#[1] 1 3 4 1 3
```

Here, the `length` is 5 i.e. more than the `length` of the `list`.  It could also be equal just by coincidence

Comment: Great callout akrun. The offending values in this list are of the format `$'17027407-f95b-40c4-8802-25945b5a82c2'
integer(0)`